# Way to Center Content with Theme CSS in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, alignment, center

I’m trying to figure out a CSS way to center my content. Here is my site: http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/?preview_id=41&preview_nonce=58439a219d&_thumbnail_id=-1&preview=true.

Notice how the content sticks to the left for the home page? I want to keep the 720 px width in the #wrapper #main-content of my CSS, but I’m not sure how to center align the content and get it to appear in the middle of the screen. I’d like to just have the left-aligned text (the text will stay left-aligned, as the content will be centered) start in the center. I've already tried text-align, align-content, margin: 0, and a few others, but I may have their placement wrong because I haven't become fully adept at reading this particular CSS page.

Ultimately, the text would be aligned left, and the content would be in the center. I'm trying to change the positioning of the content, itself, which should take the text (which will still be aligned left, with it). Any ideas?

Here is some of the overarching CSS for my site and Wordpress theme:

```
#header,
#main-content,
#wrapper-footer {
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;        
}     
#wrapper #main-content {
  padding: 28px 28px 10px;
  width: 720px;         
}
#content {
  float: left;
  width: 750px;       
}
```

I was able to change the width of the #wrapper #main-content from 956px to 720px, which is about the size that I want for my content to be, but I want it centered! I'm not sure how to do that, and as stated, I have tried various methods. Maybe I'm editing the wrong items for this specific purpose?

I can provide the rest of the CSS I currently have if needed, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed your style.css declares a float left on your main-content. Maybe this is because normally there is a sidebar there. A simple solution would be to have this:

```
#wrapper #main-content {
     padding: 28px 28px 10px;
     width: 720px;
     margin: 0 auto; //<-- added this line
     float: none; //<-- added this line
}
```

You would have to ensure this comes after other style declarations on the page.

**UPDATED**

Very true. It will affect every page. In the body class of your theme, it prints the page-id-{number} for posts. So you can have very specific css just for this page, or create very specific css for any other page you choose. This should work:

```
 .page-id-41 #main-content {
     float: none;
     margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

*Side note - I accidentally added the answer to your initial question - but I've removed it and have added it here*

Comment: Thanks! That worked, but I ended up having to do "float:none" to another line of code. Thank you for the help, cheers!

Comment: Oh and one last thing! So upon doing the above, it (naturally) threw off some of the spacing of other pages on my site. This is to be expected, but I was wondering this: what is a way I can NOT have this particular change affect one specific page on my site? I basically just want to bypass this code for page-id X. So on this page, the content would not be centered, and would just be as it was beforehand. Again, thanks for all the help.

Comment: Of course - my bad @wbhyatt. To target a specific page in your theme, you can look at the body class. I've updated my initial answer above.

Comment: I'm going to try it out soon, but this seems like just what I need. Beautiful. Thanks for being such a baller :)